# std::format error : basic_format_string<char *>' is not a constant expression

Tags: c++, stdformat

Here is  the code

```
        m_state.script_file(
            ( std::filesystem::path{ xorstr_( "magma/luas" ) } /= name ).string( ),
            [ & ] ( lua_State* const state, sol::protected_function_result result ) {
                if ( !result.valid( ) )
                    valve::g_cvar->con_print( false, 0xff0000ffu,
                        std::format( xorstr_( "can't load {}, reason: {}.\n" ), name, sol::error{ result }.what( ) ).data( )
                    );

                return result;
            }
        );
```

Error Msg

```
call to consteval function 'std::basic_format_string<char, const std::basic_string<char> &, const char *>::basic_format_string<char *>' is not a constant expression
```

when I use llvm12.0 all fine but when I change to llvm 15.0.1 it show that error

I change it to fmt::format but still not working

Answer (score 2):

Format string must be known at compile time by default. Right now you can use `std::vformat` with a runtime format string:

```cpp
std::vformat(xorstr_("can't load {}, reason: {}.\n"),
             std::make_format_args(name, sol::error{result}.what()))
```

There is a proposal to add direct support for runtime format strings to `std::format` similar to [`fmt::runtime`](https://fmt.dev/latest/api.html#_CPPv4N3fmt7runtimeE11string_view) in {fmt}.